# Editable CountIfs Formula with Dynamic Range

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I'm trying to create a macro in excel with a dynamic range for Column C and Column E in my report with Cell J2 being my reference for the last argument of my formula.

The formula I am currently working with is as follows:

```
=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$97, "\<\>33",$E$2:$E$97,J2,$C$2:$C$97, "\<\>55",$E$2:$E$97,J2,$C$2:$C$97, "\<\>10",$E$2:$E$97,J2,$C$2:$C$97, "\<\>76",$E$2:$E$97,J2)
```

I searched for various samples online to test, but couldn't find anything that worked for my application, and since I don't know VBA, my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $E$2:$E$97;J2 once in the formula.
Without the "ESCAPE CHARACTER" \ works:

```
=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$97; "<>33";$C$2:$C$97; "<>55";$C$2:$C$97; "<>10";$E$2:$E$97;J2;$C$2:$C$97; "<>76")
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to count how many cells equal `"\<\>33"` AND `"\<\>55"`, etc? This will always be 0. A single cell cannot equal 2 different things at the same time.

Are you trying to count how many cells equal `"\<\>33"` OR `"\<\>55"`, etc? Try using the formula like this:

```
=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$97, "\<\>33",$E$2:$E$97,J2) + COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$97, "\<\>55",$E$2:$E$97,J2) + COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$97, "\<\>10",$E$2:$E$97,J2) + COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$97, "\<\>76",$E$2:$E$97,J2)
```